# IRequestCycleProcessor in Apache wicket 6.X and 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-7

I am using wicket 1.4.9 Now migrating to newer version 7 or 6 , 
How to use below code in 6.6.0

```
protected IRequestCycleProcessor newRequestCycleProcessor() {
        return new WebRequestCycleProcessor() {
            protected IRequestCodingStrategy newRequestCodingStrategy() {
                return new CryptedUrlWebRequestCodingStrategy(super.newRequestCodingStrategy());
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Wicket 7 Try this in your Application;

```
setRootRequestMapper(new CryptoMapper(getRootRequestMapper(),this));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [CryptoMapper](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/f4edcd82b9f6ae5c31a0d4c468b0c6caa59fa674/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/core/request/mapper/CryptoMapper.java).

To configure it add the following in YourApplication#init() method:

```
setRootRequestMapper(new CryptoMapper(getRootRequestMapper(), this));
```

Comment: Here CryptoMapper requires 2 parameters, i can't pass null in place of 2nd place
setRootRequestMapper(new CryptoMapper(wrappedMapper, application));

Comment: I believe your answer should encouraged, +1.